# Rewrite all from http to https with htaccess but response with a error code to rest api

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rest, mod-rewrite

I have already redirect all the requests from http to https with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem is that I don't want when someone makes a request on our rest api to redirect to https but to return an error code.
Rest api path looks like this /api/[endpoints].

So my question is how I can redirect page traffic to https but stop rest requests to http with an error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a separate rule for rest api:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^api/ - [L,R=410,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your rules before reply and everything looks to work great.

Comment: I did it but I had to wait 4 minutes. Thanks again.